# Advanced Custom Fields Plugin - not displaying images

Tags: plugins, custom-field

I installed the plugin and assigned it to the relevant page but the problem is that the custom fields display 'no image selected' after I have uploaded them and do not appear on the relevant page. Any ideas?

For reference, I have set 'Page Template' as equal to 'Home' (the relevant page) on the custom fields rules.

This is the code I am using to call the image on the template:

```
<img src="<? the_field ('image_2'); ?>" class="middle" alt="image2"/>
```

Comment: You're missing the php after the question mark at the beginning. That might be the only problem.

Comment: Thanks, that definitely needed to be added but it is still not linking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you use the correct format in Advanced Custom Fields when you set up the field?

It has an option to return the attachment ID or the image URL when you create the field. So to use it this way you'd have to be sure that it was outputting the image URL not the attachment ID.